# Unix SCP/copy using list of filenames

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh, scp

I have 2 servers:

- Server A: /opt/medias - ~1milion files
- Server B: /opt/medias - Empty

I want an SCP command to copy from Server A to Server B around 60% (~750GB) of the files. I can create a txt file with the filenames I need in server B. Is there a way to achieve that? Is there a better alternative to SCP?

Thanks!!

Comment: SCP is too talky. That can slow things down considerably, specially if the round trip latency between the two servers is high. In those cases: `ssh A tar czf - --files-from list-of-files.txt | tar xzf -`

Comment: [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org) may be worth a try.

Comment: @salva does that work for ~750GB data? Is there a way to have a text file defining the names which I want to copy?

Comment: @Biffen Is there a way to have a text file defining the names which I want to copy using rsync?

Comment: It will take its time, but it should work. As an improvement, you could divide the list of files to transfer so that if something fails you don't have to start from the beginning. Use `--files-from`, read `tar` man page!

Answer (score 0):

if you still want SCP, scp all files:

```
scp -r /opt/medias/* root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/opt/medias/
```

but, as the above ppl said, you should try rsync

or

bash script to SCP only specific files (put the /usr/local/src/listOfFileNames.txt on Server A)

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
        #scp one file at a time to your other server
        scp $line root@192.168.2.3:/opt/medias/

done < /usr/local/src/listOfFileNames.txt
```

Comment: 1) can't do all files because not enough HDD space in Server B

Comment: 2) Can't do that bash script as this is RSA token authentication :( every minute the passcode changes....

Comment: so your server B changes passcode every minute ... what abour your server A? Does server A also changes passcode every minute?